# How to compare values in JavaScript for minimum order quantity

Tags: javascript

Ok, basically I have been given the task of producing a payment page for us.
I'm having a little problem. My boss wants me to integrate google checkout, and I have that working fine.
He also wants me to define an order minimum.

For example:  we sell labels at "£11.00" per "1000", but the minimum invoice is "£33.00"

I have setup my page with 4 boxes. One is qty (Quantity), another is cost (Price) and two hidden fields.
One of these fields is for google checkout (the product prices)
the final field is a hidden field I put there, to try to compare the prices and update the cost.

Currently, I have on my quantity change textbox onChange event, this:

```
function labels_1 () {
    var cost;
    var costper1k = '11.00';
    var qty = orderform.labels_1_qty.value;
    if ( isNaN( qty ) ) {
        orderform.labels_1_cost.value = "Not a Valid Quantity";
    }
    else if ( qty < 0 ) {
        orderform.labels_1_cost.value = "Negative Quantity";
    }
    else {
         cost = ((qty/1000)*costper1k);
     }

    orderform.labels_1_cost.value = formatCurrency(cost);
    orderform.hiddenprice_1.value = cost;
    orderform.prodprice_1.value = orderform.labels_1_cost.value;
    orderform.productname_1.value='26x44mm (4a) 76mm Cores'+' x '+orderform.labels_1_qty.value;
 }
```

This is working well, without the validation of minimum invoice amount.

I have this 6 functions, all like this because we sell 6 label types. As I said, google checkout works fine with all these.

I tried creating this:

```
    function hidden_1 () {
    var cost = '33.00';
    var originalcost = orderform.labels_1_cost.value;
    var a = Number(orderform.hidden_1.value);
    var b = Number(orderform.hidden_2.value);
    var c = Number(orderform.hidden_3.value);
    var d = Number(orderform.hidden_4.value);
    var e = Number(orderform.hidden_5.value);
    var f = Number(orderform.hidden_6.value);
    var total = a+b+c+d+e+f;
    if (total.value < '33'){
    orderform.labels_1_cost.value = formatCurrency(cost);}
    if (total.value > '33') {
    orderform.labels_1_cost.value = originalcost;}

}
```

and appending hidden_1(); to the end of the label_1() function.

It doesn't work, And I am tearing my hair out trying to fix it. I'm not even sure I am doing that right.

Can Anyone offer any help?
many thanks

**edit**

Sorry, here is my formatCurrency function:

```
function formatCurrency(num) {
num = num.toString().replace(/\$|\,/g,'');
if(isNaN(num))
num = "0";
sign = (num == (num = Math.abs(num)));
num = Math.floor(num*100+0.50000000001);
cents = num%100;
num = Math.floor(num/100).toString();
if(cents<10)
cents = "0" + cents;
for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor((num.length-(1+i))/3); i++)
num = num.substring(0,num.length-(4*i+3))+','+
num.substring(num.length-(4*i+3));
return (((sign)?'':'-') + '£' + num + '.' + cents);
```

}

Full Site Code:
Order.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">@import "css/forms-style.css";</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/labels.js"></script>
</head>

<script id="googlecart-script" type="text/javascript"
  src="http://checkout.google.com/seller/gsc/v2/cart.js?mid=REMOVED!!!"
  currency="GBP"
  highlight-time="5000"
  highlight-color="#FF7878"
  cart-opening-time="500"
  hide-cart-when-empty="true"
  close-cart-when-click-away="false"
  post-cart-to-sandbox="true">
</script>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">

<form name="orderform">
<!-- ----------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
<div id="content">
<div class="heading-section">
<h2>Printed Labels</h2>
<p>All Printed Labels come outside wound, with a standard <strong>10 item setups per roll.</strong></p>
<p>The minimum Invoice amount is <strong>&pound;30.00</strong></p>
</div>
<div align="center" id="statement">Hover Over Images To Zoom</div>
<br/>
<p>
  <?php tableformat( '1', '26x44mm (4a) 76mm Cores','26x44mm Labels. Custom options are available for these labels. They can include the text SPECIAL BUY or SPECIAL PURCHASE overprinted in <font color=red><strong>RED</strong></font> ink. These labels can also include a Country of Origin and the John lewis Address. The labels are also available in blockout (opaque) backing, to be used for repricing, or generally covering other labels.','Style: <select class="product-attr-color">
          <option>Normal</option>
          <option>Special Buy</option>
      <option>Special Purchase</option>
      <option>Opaque Backing Material</option>
        </select>','img/img_1.png','img/img_7.png','img/img_8.png','img/img_1_thumb.png','img/img_7_thumb.png','img/img_8_thumb.png' ); ?>
  <?php tableformat( '2', '44x26mm (2a) 76mm Cores','44x26mm Labels. Custom options are available for these labels. They can include the text SPECIAL BUY or SPECIAL PURCHASE overprinted in <font color=red><strong>RED</strong></font> ink. These labels can also include a Country of Origin and the John lewis Address. The labels are also available in blockout (opaque) backing, to be used for repricing, or generally covering other labels.','Style: <select class="product-attr-color">
          <option>Normal</option>
          <option>Special Buy</option>
      <option>Special Purchase</option>
      <option>Opaque Backing Material</option>
        </select>','img/img_2.png','','','img/img_2_thumb.png','','' ); ?>
  <?php tableformat( '3', '35x13mm (2a) 76mm Cores','35x13mm Labels. These Labels can include a Country of Origin. Please Note, the size of the label is fairly limited','','img/img_3.png','','','img/img_3_thumb.png','','' ); ?>
  <?php tableformat( '4', '80x10mm [dumbells] (1a) 76mm Cores','80x10mm Dumbell Labels. These Labels can be produced with either an EAN8 or an EAN13 consumer code','','img/img_4.png','','','img/img_4_thumb.png','','' ); ?>
  <?php tableformat( '5', '25x10mm [price only] (4a) 76mm Cores','25x10mm Labels. These Small labels may include a Price Only. No text will be printed on these labels. If you require Text, please look at some of the other sizes above','','img/img_5.png','','','img/img_5_thumb.png','','' ); ?>
  <?php tableformat( '6', '15x8mm [price only] (4a) 76mm Cores','15x8mm Labels. These Small labels may include a Price Only. No text will be printed on these labels. If you require Text, please look at some of the other sizes above','','img/img_6.png','','','img/img_6_thumb.png','','' ); ?>
</p>  
<div class="heading-section" align="right">
<input type="reset">

<!-- ----------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
</hr>
</h2>
</div>
</div>
</form>

<br/><br/>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<?php

function tableformat( $num, $label, $labeldesc, $options, $pic1, $pic2, $pic3, $thumb1, $thumb2, $thumb3) {

echo
'<div id="'.$num.'" class="section">
<div class="product">
<table border=0 width=100% align=center class="product-table">
<tr valign=top bgcolor=3366cc>
        <td colspan=4><span class="product-name">'.$label.'</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="p1" href="#v"><img onerror="this.style.display=\'none\'" src="'.$thumb1.'" alt=""><b><img class="large" onerror="this.style.display=\'none\'" src="'.$pic1.'" alt=""></b></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="p1" onerror="this.style.display=\'none\'" ;href="#v"><img onerror="this.style.display=\'none\'" src="'.$thumb2.'" alt=""><b><img onerror="this.style.display=\'none\'" class="large" src="'.$pic2.'" alt=""></b></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="p1" href="#v"><img onerror="this.style.display=\'none\'" src="'.$thumb3.'" alt=""><b><img class="large" onerror="this.style.display=\'none\'" src="'.$pic3.'" alt=""></b></a></td>
        <input type="hidden" name="productname_'.$num.'" class="product-title" value="0"/>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="left" colspan="2">
        <span id="labels_'.$num.'_exp">'.$labeldesc.'</span>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign=center align=right>
    <td width=30%>
    &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td width=auto>
    '.$options.'
    <strong>Quantity:</strong> <input type="text" name="labels_'.$num.'_qty" size="10" value=0 onChange="OnChan();">
    <strong>Price:</strong> <input type="text" name="labels_'.$num.'_cost" class="form-cost" size="10" value="0.00" onChange="OnChan();">
    <input type="hidden" name="prodprice_'.$num.'" class="product-price" value="£0.00"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenprice_'.$num.'" value="0.00"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <td width=30%>
    &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td width=auto align=right>
    <div role="button" alt="Add to cart" tabindex="0" class="googlecart-add-button" onClick="hidden_'.$num.';">
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
<br/>
<br/>

</div></div>';


} // tableformat

?>
```

labels.js is here:

```
function formatCurrency(num) {
    num = num.toString().replace(/\$|\,/g,'');
    if(isNaN(num))
    num = "0";
    sign = (num == (num = Math.abs(num)));
    num = Math.floor(num*100+0.50000000001);
    cents = num%100;
    num = Math.floor(num/100).toString();
    if(cents<10)
    cents = "0" + cents;
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor((num.length-(1+i))/3); i++)
    num = num.substring(0,num.length-(4*i+3))+','+
    num.substring(num.length-(4*i+3));
    return (((sign)?'':'-') + '£' + num + '.' + cents);
}

function isPositiveInteger(val){
    if(val==null){return false;}
    if (val.length==0){return false;}
    for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
        var ch = val.charAt(i)
        if (ch < "0" || ch > "9") {
        return false
        }
    }
    return true;
}

/* -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    LABELS - 1
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

function labels_1 () {
    var cost, desc;
    var costper1k = '11.00';
    var qty = orderform.labels_1_qty.value;
    if ( isNaN( qty ) ) {
        orderform.labels_1_cost.value = "Not a Valid Quantity";
        desc = 'Not a Valid Quantity';
    }
    else if ( qty < 0 ) {
        orderform.labels_1_cost.value = "Negative Quantity";
        desc = 'Not a Valid Quantity';
    }
    else {
         cost = ((qty/1000)*costper1k);
         desc = qty+' ordered at a cost of '+formatCurrency(cost);
         }

    orderform.labels_1_cost.value = formatCurrency(cost);
    alert("test - end of normal");
    hidden_1();
}


/* -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Hidden - 1
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
function hidden_1 () {
    alert("starting");
    var costed = '33.00';
    var originalcost = orderform.labels_1_cost.value;
    var a = Number(orderform.hidden_1.value);
    var b = Number(orderform.hidden_2.value);
    var c = Number(orderform.hidden_3.value);
    var d = Number(orderform.hidden_4.value);
    var e = Number(orderform.hidden_5.value);
    var f = Number(orderform.hidden_6.value);
    var total = a+b+c+d+e+f;
    if (total < 33){
    orderform.labels_1_cost.value = costed;}
    if (total => 33) {
    orderform.labels_1_cost.value = originalcost;}
    alert("ending");
}


/* -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    LABELS - 2
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */




function labels_2 () {
    var cost, desc;
    var costper1k = '11.00';
    var qty = orderform.labels_2_qty.value;
    if ( isNaN( qty ) ) {
        orderform.labels_2_cost.value = "Not a Valid Quantity";
        desc = 'Not a Valid Quantity';
    }
    else if ( qty < 0 ) {
        orderform.labels_2_cost.value = "Negative Quantity";
        desc = 'Not a Valid Quantity';
    }
    else {
         cost = ((qty/1000)*costper1k);
         desc = qty+' ordered at a cost of '+formatCurrency(cost);
         }
    orderform.labels_2_cost.value = formatCurrency(cost);
}

/* -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    LABELS - 3
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

function labels_3 () {
    var cost, desc;
    var costper1k = '11.00';
    var qty = orderform.labels_3_qty.value;
    if ( isNaN( qty ) ) {
        orderform.labels_3_cost.value = "Not a Valid Quantity";
        desc = 'Not a Valid Quantity';
    }
    else if ( qty < 0 ) {
        orderform.labels_3_cost.value = "Negative Quantity";
        desc = 'Not a Valid Quantity';
    }
    else{
         cost = ((qty/1000)*costper1k);
         desc = qty+' ordered at a cost of '+formatCurrency(cost);
        }
    orderform.labels_3_cost.value = formatCurrency(cost);
}

/* -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    LABELS - 4
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

function labels_4 () {
    var cost, desc;
    var costper1k = '13.75';
    var qty = orderform.labels_4_qty.value;
    if ( isNaN( qty ) ) {
        orderform.labels_4_cost.value = "Not a Valid Quantity";
        desc = 'Not a Valid Quantity';
    }
    else if ( qty < 0 ) {
        orderform.labels_4_cost.value = "Negative Quantity";
        desc = 'Not a Valid Quantity';
    }
    else {
         cost = ((qty/1000)*costper1k);
         desc = qty+' ordered at a cost of '+formatCurrency(cost);
        }
    orderform.labels_4_cost.value = formatCurrency(cost);
}

/* -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    LABELS - 5
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

function labels_5 () {
    var cost, desc;
    var costper1k = '7.89';
    var qty = orderform.labels_5_qty.value;
    if ( isNaN( qty ) ) {
        orderform.labels_5_cost.value = "Not a Valid Quantity";
        desc = 'Not a Valid Quantity';
    }
    else if ( qty < 0 ) {
        orderform.labels_5_cost.value = "Negative Quantity";
        desc = 'Not a Valid Quantity';
    }
    else {
         cost = ((qty/1000)*costper1k);
         desc = qty+' ordered at a cost of '+formatCurrency(cost);
        }
    orderform.labels_5_cost.value = formatCurrency(cost);
}


/* -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    LABELS - 6
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
function labels_6 () {
    var cost, desc;
    var costper1k = '10.14';
    var qty = orderform.labels_6_qty.value;
    if ( isNaN( qty ) ) {
        orderform.labels_6_cost.value = "Not a Valid Quantity";
        desc = 'Not a Valid Quantity';
    }
    else if ( qty < 0 ) {
        orderform.labels_6_cost.value = "Negative Quantity";
        desc = 'Not a Valid Quantity';
    }
    else {
         cost = ((qty/1000)*costper1k);
         desc = qty+' ordered at a cost of '+formatCurrency(cost);
        }
    orderform.labels_6_cost.value = formatCurrency(cost);
}

/* -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    OnChan (Changes)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

function OnChan () {
labels_1();
labels_2();
labels_3();
labels_4();
labels_5();
labels_6();
orderform.prodprice_1.value=orderform.labels_1_cost.value;
orderform.prodprice_2.value=orderform.labels_2_cost.value;
orderform.prodprice_3.value=orderform.labels_3_cost.value;
orderform.prodprice_4.value=orderform.labels_4_cost.value;
orderform.prodprice_5.value=orderform.labels_5_cost.value;
orderform.prodprice_6.value=orderform.labels_6_cost.value;
orderform.productname_1.value='26x44mm (4a) 76mm Cores'+' x '+orderform.labels_1_qty.value;
orderform.productname_2.value='44x26mm (2a) 76mm Cores'+' x '+orderform.labels_2_qty.value;
orderform.productname_3.value='35x13mm (2a) 76mm Cores'+' x '+orderform.labels_3_qty.value;
orderform.productname_4.value='80x10mm [dumbells] (1a) 76mm Cores'+' x '+orderform.labels_4_qty.value;
orderform.productname_5.value='25x10mm [price only] (4a) 76mm Cores'+' x '+orderform.labels_5_qty.value;
orderform.productname_6.value='15x8mm [price only] (4a) 76mm Cores'+' x '+orderform.labels_6_qty.value;

}
```

and a test website is up at:

http://mrotacon.heliohost.org/testing/order.php

also - here is a test version without the comparison, which works fine... but i need the minimum invoice amount

http://mrotacon.heliohost.org/testing/orderworking.php

Comment: your code is so wet. you should try looking for a way to make is DRY(Dont-Repeat-Yourself).

Comment: I will, don't worry - just need a quick page for now, when I have some actual free time I will change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say how it's not working and what diagnostics you've got but... might it be because you're comparing strings rather than numeric values?  So, for example, '6' > '33'.  That "total.value" looks dodgy to me too.

Comment: Basically its not updating the orderform.labels_1_cost.value as I intend it to do. Its keeping the original value of orderform.labels_1_cost.value.

For example:

If I enter 500 in the quantity - the price is £5.50
I want it to see that this is below the minimum invoice order of £33.00, and change the value to this.

It has to compare the values in orderform.labels_1_cost.value, orderform.labels_2_cost.value, orderform.labels_3_cost.value, orderform.labels_4_cost.value, orderform.labels_5_cost.value and orderform.labels_6_cost.value

These all default at value="0.00" and changes with quantity

Comment: Try getting rid of the .value in the use of total and make '33' 33 in the conditional criteria then give it a go.

Comment: You should make it '>=' rather than '>' too (otherwise what happens when it's 33 exactly?).

Comment: Hi Trevor. Sorry, that didn't work... should that work how I have done it?

Do you want to see the site?

Comment: Have you just tried outputting alert() messages or writing debug text into a debug div on the page?  So you can get to see the value of total that you're comparing and whether you're even triggering the hidden_1() function?

Comment: there is def a problem with my hidden_1.
It works, as it is - without it - i add an alert("endoflabel"); instead of hidden and it pops up.
I remove alert, and add hidden_1(); to c all the hidden_1 function

At the start of hidden i add an alert and one at the end, and i add an alert before hidden is called... now no alerts pop up at all

Comment: @Trevor Tippins
Can you offer any more help please... Have updated my post with quite a bit more info

Comment: I'll take a quick look at the test site and see what my friend Firebug has to say.

Comment: One syntax error: labels2.js:72: "if (total => 33) {" should be "if (total >= 33) {"

Comment: Cheers - changed that one, im getting the alerts now - its dying before the final alert though - so it does initiate the hidden_1 function... i will add line by line alerts

Comment: Do you use Firebug or the Chrome / IE8 equivalents?  Really useful for stuff like this.

Comment: i haven't used it
Only used chromes element inspection
Gonna take a look at it now

Hmm - the last alert i see  - is alert 2
`alert("2");
    var a = Number(orderform.hidden_1.value);
    alert("3");
    var b = Number(orderform.hidden_2.value);`

Looks like it doesn't like Number(orderform.hidden_1.value)

Comment: Looking at the DOM it doesn't appear that the orderform.hidden_1 element exists. You've got some called hiddenprice_n though.

Comment: My God its `<input type="hidden" name="hiddenprice_'.$num.'" value="0.00"/>` hiddenprice - why did i miss that?!? Lol - i'll try now see if it gets past it

Comment: you sir are a GOD!      i got part of it working, it actually changes the price to £33 now, now i'll look at my if statement.
Have a beer on me - I'm gonna have to leave the office and work on it at home - will post later

Comment: No problem. Sometimes it helps having another set of eyes on the problem. Have a good evening. Don't forget to accept this answer!!